# Is it possible to use wildcards in the .htaccess file for mass moves?

Tags: .htaccess, file-io, wildcard, directory-structure

I am reworking my website, going to be renaming a lot of directories, and need a simple way to write my .htaccess redirects for all of those pages. I am hoping for a solution that does not include a very long list of files. My .htaccess file is huge as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [mod_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) or [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for your redirecting. mod_rewrite works with regular expressions and mod_alias can work on both regular expression and path prefixes.

Here are some examples for when you want to rewrite `/foo/…` to `/bar/…`:

```
# mod_alias
# path prefix
Redirect 301 /foo /bar
# regular expression
RedirectMatch 301 ^/foo/(.*) /bar/$1

# mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^foo/(.*) /bar/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Note that mod_alias and mod_rewrite have different requirements for their regular expressions patterns. mod_alias does always require the full URL path. But with mod_rewrite it depends on whether you use it in a .htaccess file or in the server configuration/virtual host section. In a .htaccess file, you need to write the pattern without the per-directory path prefix (in case of the document root just `/`, in case of `/quux/` it’s `/quux/`).

Comment: I can't get the formatting to work, sorry.

I did something wrong when using the above. I wrote...
 
    Redirect 301 /fantasy/v /fantasy/opinions
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/fantasy/v/(.*) /fantasy/opinions/$1

but that caused a internal server error for my whole site. Then I tried this...

    Redirect 301 http://www.xecu.net/fantasy/v http://www.xecu.net/fantasy/opinions
    RedirectMatch 301 http://www.xecu.net/fantasy/v(.*) http://www.xecu.net/fantasy/opinions$1

That didn't cause an error, but didn't work. What did I do wrong?